# How to run code after an IPython kernel restart

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I'm running this code in spyder using python-64bit ver3.6.5. Can someone help me how can I run commands after ipython restarts

```
import IPython
import time

def restart_ipyhton():
    app = IPython.Application.instance()
    app.kernel.do_shutdown(True)  

print('before restart')
restart_ipyhton()
time.sleep(10)
print('after restart')
```

[Even though I specified a delay of 10 seconds, ipython kernel executed the statements "print('after restart')" before it died. Can someone help me how can I run commands after ipython restarts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta3n5.png)

Comment: Please click on the higlighted paragraph to see my image of output in spyder ipython console

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In short, to solve out of memory of a thrid party API call that is too much memory. I'm running into memory issues after firing more than a certain number of calls to a thrid party application API using python. So, I want to kill ipython in spyder after certain calls and restart my kernel to complete the rest of the calls.

Comment: You could free the memory. Alternatively you could use the ipython magic to clear all variables. This would lead pretty much to a "new" kernel.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The problem is that kernel restarts are asynchronous calls, i.e. they are executed in an external process and there's no way to tell from code when that call finished and when a new kernel is available. That's because code is run in the kernel that's going to be killed.

So, as far as I can tell, it's not possible to do what you want (but I'm no expert in the Jupyter architecture).